# Heteroscedasticity in Fixed Effects model

Tags: panel-data, heteroscedasticity

I've found heteroscedasticity in my panel data. However, Gujarati (2009) says in a footnote to the chapter "The fixed-effect within group estimator" that Stata provides heteroscedasticity-corrected standard errors in panel data regression models. Does this mean that I can ignore the heteroscedasticity found?

Answer (score 1):

The option `vce(robust)` for regress, xtreg etc... produces heteroskedasticity consistent standard errors. Note also that heteroskedasticity robust standard errors in a regression with fixed effects is produced in Stata by clustering on the panel's grouping variable.

Theoretically, heteroskedasticity robust standard errors will produce consistent estimates in the presence of heteroskedasticity (as your sample size goes to infinity), but of course, all bets are off for too small a sample.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.I'd just like to know when the feasible generalized least squares (xtgls); should be used instead of the robust fixed effect model.

Comment: So vce(robust) option with fixed effects just fixes up your standard errors taking into account how your various observations may be correlated. GLS will take into account *in the estimation phase* some estimate of the covariance in your error terms. If the covariance structure is accurate, that can seriously improve efficiency. On the other hand, if the covariance structure/estimate is junk, it can introduce serious error. Basically, instead of weighting each observation equally, you're assigning more weight to less noisy observations, but if they're not less noisy, shit may hit the fan.

Comment: That's my extremely loose, high level take anyway. I'm not familiar with the all the particulars of 'xtgls' in Stata.

Comment: Is it true that the sandwich estimator is equivalent to the cluster-sandwich estimator? I think not. Or maybe you're referring to a state default?

Comment: @generic_user From the Stata [technical notes for xtreg](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/xtxtreg.pdf) on page 25, "As discussed
by Wooldridge (2013), Stock and Watson (2008), and Arellano (2003), specifying vce(robust) is equivalent to specifying vce(cluster panelvar), where panelvar is the variable that identifies the panels."

Comment: @MatthewGunn OK, I assume that under-the-hood stata knows the difference between $(X'X)^{-1}X'\hat{\epsilon}\hat{\epsilon}'X(X'X)^{-1}$ and $(X'X)^{-1}\displaystyle\sum_j \left(X_j'\hat{\epsilon_j}\hat{\epsilon_j}'X_j\right)(X'X)^{-1}$

Comment: @generic_user For fixed $T$ in panel data, the usual heteroskedastic-robust standard-errors are inconsistent. See [Stock and Watson (2008)](https://www.princeton.edu/~mwatson/papers/ecta6489.pdf). Stata changed how it calculates vce(robust) in [I think version 10 or so](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2010-07/msg00899.html)? I changed my language to reflect this approach may be Stata specific.

Comment: @MatthewGunn right, this is true.  Stata doesn't let you make the wrong choice, apparently.